# Starting broadcast receiver from another receiver (Boot up receiver)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my application I have a Boot up receiver, So when device reboots, I want to wake up another receivers.So please help me.
Below is my code :

```
public class BootUpReciever extends BroadcastReceiver{

Context context;
SharedPreferences settings;
SmsManager smsMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent sms = new Intent(context, SMSReceiver.class);
    sms.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(sms);

    Intent netAvailability = new Intent(context, CheckingNetworkAvailability.class);
    netAvailability.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(netAvailability); 
}    }
```

here SMSReceiver.class and heckingNetworkAvailability.class are my receivers.
Is there any mistake I am doing.

Comment: So the receivers are actually Activities? Or do those activities register their own receivers?

Comment: I dont know dear Can you give me a hint

Comment: Well it's clear you are starting Activities, which differ from BroadcastReceivers. My question is, do those Activities have a `registerReceiver()` call in them?

Comment: Hey got the solution and my code is just below....

Answer (score 0):

Now I am using package manager and its working fine :)

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    ComponentName sms = new ComponentName(context, SMSReceiver.class);
    context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(sms, 
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    ComponentName net = new ComponentName(context, CheckingNetworkAvailability.class);
    context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(net, 
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```